# Does onSaveInstanceState always save my Member variables in Fragment？

Tags: android, android-fragments

I switch fragment when onDestroyedView() is called,member variables will be kept, and when onDestroy() is called, I could restore them from bundle, because onSaveInstanceState is called before onDestroy().But now I face a problem that member variables were reset to their initial values,I have look up lots of documents but I don't know why it could happen?

Answer (score 1):

> Does onSaveInstanceState always save my Member variables in Fragment？

No. `onSaveInstanceState()` saves whatever you put in the `Bundle` that is passed in as a parameter. You then get the values back out of that `Bundle` in `onCreate()` or other fragment lifecycle methods.

Comment: Yeah, So did I. But it seems that member variables in the fragment are not restored but reset?Is it possible that member variables are reset while i save data in onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onActivityCreated()?